# Get all images from website

Tags: command-line, wget

I'm trying to wget all the images pictures from a website. I thought I knew how to use it, but I guess I don't.

The images I'm trying to get come from [here](http://gameinfo.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/).

The command I'm using is:

```
wget -prA.png http://gameinfo.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/
```

But I only get a index.html back?

Could somebody explain this?

Comment: See also  http://www.httrack.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The web page uses dynamic HTML to display the champion grid content (just look at the HTML source of the page and search for "Champion Grid", the only thing under that is some empty `div`s. Since `wget` doesn't do javascript, it won't execute the code that would generate the grid HTML (and link the images).

Comment: I thought that but I didn't knew wget couldn't get this. Thank you for your answer and I will find a different way